# Decrease version number

Tags: shell, awk, version

I'm creating a while loop which stops when it reaches a specific version.
The issue is that if I have version 1.1.4 and want to go down to 1.0.9, my `awk` command that I've found on this forum doesn't do well.

I'm using something like this:

```
while compare versions; do

    current version=

    if [[ actual version != current version ]]; then

        currentver=

        previous version=`echo $ current version | awk -F. -v OFS=. \ 
              'NF==1{print ++$NF};
               NF>1{if(length($NF+1)>length($NF))$(NF-1)++;
               $NF=sprintf("%0*d", length($NF), ($NF-1)%(10^length($NF))); 
               print}'`

        Go back to $ previous version

        do something
```

What I get is:

```
Go back to 1.1.4

Go back to 1.1.3

Go back to 1.1.2

Go back to 1.1.1

Go back to 1.1.0

Go back to 1.1.-1

Go back to 1.1.-2
```

I want the version number to go to 1.0.9.

How can I change the `awk` command not to go below 0?

Comment: But what if 1.0.10 exists?

Comment: Please clarify whether the goal is to count down with dot separated numbers, or to countdown using a list of known versions, (extracted from a *changelog* file perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

A little `bash` and `sed`:

```
echo "version_1."{104..099} | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sed 's/.\(.$\)/.\1/g;y/_/ /'
```

Output:

```
version 1.1.4
version 1.1.3
version 1.1.2
version 1.1.1
version 1.1.0
version 1.0.9
```

---

Another similar method:

```
echo "version_"{114..109} | sed 's/ /\n/g;y/_/ /;s/\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\1.\2./g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear so if this isn't what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function decrement(old,        n,parts) {
    n = split(old,parts,/\./)
    if ( parts[n] == 0 ) {
        parts[n--] = 9
    }
    parts[n]--
    return (parts[1] "." parts[2] "." parts[3])
}
BEGIN {
    val = "1.1.4"
    while ( val != "1.0.9" ) {
        print val
        val = decrement(val)
    }
    print val
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
1.1.4
1.1.3
1.1.2
1.1.1
1.1.0
1.0.9
```

then edit your question to clarify what you're trying to do and provide testable sample input/output.

Comment: This is what I want, I can replace 1.1.4 with $current version and 1.0.9 to $target version. But I want it to work in a shell script, and this doesn't.

Comment: Of course it does. Again, if it doesn't do what you want then you'll have to edit your question to clarify what that is.